# C++ Nested Classes: Instantiate Child Class From Main

Tags: c++, nested

I would like to declare an instance of my class outer, then use that to declare an instance of outer's child class inner. In the project I'm working on, I would like to be able to declare several instances of an inner class, using different constructors. These instantiations should be able to access the private variables in outer. This example is a simplification of my problem. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or post a working example?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class outer
{
  private:
    int x;
  public:
    outer(int input){x=input;};

  class inner
  {
    public:
      int showx(){cout<<outinst->x<<"\n";};
  };
};

int main()
{
  cout<<"hello julian\n";
  outer* clevername(5);

  //I can't make it work past this point. The desired efect is 
  //to declare an instance of outer initiated with a value of x,
  //use this instance of outer to declare an instance of inner,
  //then use this instance of inner to return the original value of x

  clevername->inner* ins;
  cout<<ins->showx()<<"\n";
};
```

Comment: Your code although short needs some serious debugging.

Comment: I don't see any instatiation of your classes, only declarations of pointers to them in main().

Comment: Downvoting because the problems with the code have little to do with the question or title.

Comment: I searched for a similar question and couldn't find anything. I'm sorry I guess this title is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested class (`inner`) is not automatically a data member of `outer` nor does an object of type `outer::inner` have any access to any private members of any object of type `outer`. Moreover, to access members of an object you need the `.` operator. Finally, you're confusing objects with pointers.
Here is an attempt at a code that does perhaps what you intended (not tried it so it may still need debugging).

```
#include <iostream>

class outer
{
    const int x;
  public:
    outer(int input) : x(input) {}
    class inner;
    friend class inner;             // inner must be friend to access private member x

    class inner
    {
        const outer* const outinst;   // const pointer to an outer object
      public:
        inner(const outer*out) : outinst(out) {}
        int showx() const
        { return outinst->x; }
    };
};

int main()
{
  std::cout<<"hello julian\n";
  outer clevername(5);              // declare object of type outer
  outer::inner ins(&clevername);    // declare object of type outer::inner
  std::cout << ins.showx() << "\n";
};
```

Note that there is no benefit or other use of the fact that `outer::inner` is a member type of `outer`, i.e. the same effect could have been achieved (more easily) by declaring `inner` as another freestanding class.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
clevername->inner* ins;
```

is wrong. Use

```
outer::inner ins;
```

instead. BTW you have also incorrect `clevername` declaration, it does not declare an object but a pointer. Do not use pointers unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: My problem is that I want to reference the value stored in clevername. If I use outer::inner ins;, will inner have access to the value of x I set when I declared clevername?

Comment: Objects of inner class does not have any kind of 'automatic' access to objects of outer class. The same for pointers. You do something fundamentally wrong. The difference between declaring two classes side by side and one in another is not big - it is only about naming and access if the inner class is private or protected.